# Cannot boot laptop (Sony VAIO y series)

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I can't access safe mode at all. Before my laptop crashed, I used a HDMI cable and I was watching a film on a TV, after that I simply switched off my laptop.

After some time, when I turn on my laptop the screen is black and I can't access safe mode with F8, also I can't "switch the screens" with Fn and F7, can somebody help me? My new laptop simply has a black screen with a blinking cursor in the left corner.

Comment: Take the battery out and let it set for a couple of minutes, then re-install the battery and try again.

Comment: I do that, but nothing changed, his screen still black :(

Comment: Sorry that did not help.